# what's the purpose of cordova-cli? and how can I install it on Fedora?

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, cordova-cli

This may be a really silly question but I'm trying to understand what is the cordova-cli command and especially what is the difference between it and the cordova CLI command.

When going to https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli or https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova I can see that they outline how to install (at Ubuntu) the cordova-cli command and afterward how to install the cordova CLI command using npm.

I tried to install the cordova-cli command at Fedora but I couldn't find how, then I got curios and I started to investigate about this command and I couldn't find any evidence which will show me that it's different from the cordova CLI beside the Ubuntu installation example...

So could anyone please shed some light on this subject?

thx!

### ------ Update

To make it clearer, this is what the manuals instruct to run:

1. sudo apt-get install cordova-cli
2. npm install -g cordova

What does "cordova-cli" from the first command do? which "cordova" from the second command don't do? OR what is "cordova-cli" ?! :)

Answer (score 0):

**cordova-cli** is the cordova command line interface, it works as a npm installation and is the entry point to create a project with cordova.

If you want tot try the installation on Fedora, i think that you must respect these prerequisites:

1. Download and install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/download/)
2. Download and install a [git client](http://git-scm.com/download/linux)
3. Install the cordova module using npm utility of Node.js:

   $ sudo npm install -g cordova

For a complete guide follow the official cordova tutorial: [cordova-cli](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html)

Hope this help!

Comment: Well I did that and actually work with cordova for quite some time but the command I get at the end is "cordova" and not "cordova-cli", I'm puzzled specifically about "cordova-cli"

Comment: cordova-cli is only a synonymous of cordova. as you post in the link *https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli* under the folder **bin** there isn't the cordova-cli command, the command is only **cordova**.
Where you find the references about a command called cordvova-cli and where you want to use it?

Comment: So y does it need both an apt-get install and npm install?

Comment: No i suggest you to use npm to install cordova CLI. If you use npm some other things ad framework and module will be very simple to download and start to work.
If you want to install cordova as apt-get i think that you can and it will work in the same way.
Mu suggestions is to follow cordova specification and use node js npm.

Comment: Also take a look at https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-cli.git;a=blob;f=doc/cordova.txt;h=97e4d8458d1c11eaf16209a5880db87410754514;hb=65460c1 the command is cordova-cli and not cordova.

btw I do aware that there isn't a lot of instances where u can c that command, but it keep popping at various places... honestly I think that I don't understand something very basic here

Comment: my problem is not with installing cordova, done that already and everything is fine, I'm just curios in regard to "cordova-cli"